# How can I compile the Linux Kernel getting the output of the preprocessor too?

Tags: gcc, compilation, linux-kernel, macros, c-preprocessor

I know that with `gcc -E` you can get the output of the preprocessor, but what I have to do to get that output for every source code file in the Linux Lernel as part of the compilation process?

Comment: Modify a CFLAGS environment variable?  Modifying **KBUILD_HOSTCFLAGS** in the top-level **Makefile** looks promising.

Comment: The `-save-temps` GCC option will save the preprocessor output to a .i file and save assembly output to a .s file. It's probably not a good idea to do that for a full kernel build.

Comment: Thank you sawdust and Ian Abbott

Comment: @IanAbbott Make this an answer?

Comment: @yugr I don't know if it would be a good answer. It might do something horrible to the build.